# Platform.GetRenderer(view) is obsolete

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui, .net-maui

So I was using this compatibility renderer that has this method `Platform.GetRenderer(view)` in both Platforms (iOS and Android) but with RC versions of Maui it seems this method has been marked obsolete does anyone have a clue whats the new way of doing this?

```
var nativeView = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.
            Platform.GetRenderer(view)?.NativeView;

var nativeView = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.
            Platform.GetRenderer(view)?.NativeView;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If I found the correct [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5322), they were made obsolete because:

> Currently we have a `Handler` version of all the legacy renderers in `Xamarin.Forms` so users will have the most success just using the `Handlers` vs using `Renderers`

Based off of the obsolete message, you should instead use `Use Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.VisualElementRenderer`.

Comment: Hey Timothy, Yes you are correct I need to use VisualElementRenderer from Compatibility which I am already doing, What I am trying to do next is use the NativeView property but the problem is that the GetRenderer method itself is obsolete , you can check [this line](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/pull/26/files#diff-f849cb822fd8981900625482acb83a66f9cb2fd5c1302fa03974a6710f262182R119) of code for more context.

Comment: @FreakyAli I'm not following what you mean - the code you linked to appears to be using `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.Platform.GetRenderer` still?  I see your class implements the `VisualElementRenderer`, but you aren't using it on this line of code. Maybe [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Compatibility/Handlers/VisualElementRenderer.cs#L222) is what you should be using instead.